# Can I get info from iOS about the connection status of a Bluetooth headset

Tags: iphone, connection, bluetooth, status

I wanted to know how could an application get info from iOS about the connection status of a Bluetooth headset. Specifically - if it is paired or not, if it is out of range or not, if it is connected or disconnected.

I have searched extensively on the net and also on stack overflow for over 4-5 hrs at stretch but not found any convincing replies.

Request people to help me out in this direction. I had approached Apple with this query but somehow their replies do not end up coming even after sending them numerous reminders.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any public API mechanism to get the info about connection status of Bluetooth Headsets.. 
Only if you build custom accessory that uses Bluetooth - mechanisms are available to be notified when the accessory connects etc. You need to sign up for the MFi program to get the details... 
But I don't think this would help you are you seem to want to detect the status of standard Bluetooth Headsets..